# i am trying to insert blob data in h2 embedded database , but it fails from classpath/URI . However it works fine with absolute path

Tags: database, spring-boot, h2, file-read

I am using spring boot 1.5.10.RELEASE which uses H2 1.4.196 version.

Please can you help on why the URI or classpath doesnt work ?

File: test1.pdf under /src/main/resources/samplepdfs

INSERT INTO CBM_DATA( DATA ) VALUES ( <> ) --> returns empty data ( file is hosted on intranet and hence cant share the URL ( uses https ) and i can access the file without any credentials

INSERT INTO CBM_DATA( DATA ) VALUES ('classpath:/samplepdfs/test1.pdf' ) --> returns empty data

Comment: INSERT INTO CBM_DATA( DATA ) VALUES (FILE_READ( <<URI>> ))
INSERT INTO CBM_DATA( DATA ) VALUES (FILE_READ('classpath:/samplepdfs/test1.pdf' ))

DATA is a BLOB In DB

Answer (score 0):

A bit old, but maybe related to this issue?

https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/446

(FILE_READ from classpath not working because of 0 byte file length)